# Binary Operator '+' cannot be applied to type 'CGRect' and 'Double'

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to change the bottom constant of a button when the keyboard appears to the height of the keyboard with an addition 8 points.

However the following

```
if let keyboardHeight = (n.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

   saveButtonBottomConstant.constant = keyboardHeight + 8.0
}
```

gives me the following error in Xcode 8.0 beta 6 when converting to Swift 3

> Binary Operator '+' cannot be applied to type 'CGRect' and 'Double'

I understand why this is happening however my attempts have caused more errors than solving the issue.

How can I simply add a Double to a CGRect value in Swift 3 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` returns the keyboard's frame in screen coordinates so `keyboardHeight` is `CGRect` type.

You can get the height of keyboard as follows:

```
if let keyboardFrame = (n.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
  saveButtonBottomConstant.constant = keyboardFrame.height + 8.0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code won't work because you're trying to add a `Double` (8.0) to a `CGRect` (`keyboardHeight`). As you're using Swift 3 `CGRectGetHeight()` is unavailable, so you should use this:

```
saveButtonBottomConstant.constant = keyboardHeight.height + 8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have either 2 Double values or 2 GCRect values. Change one of them to the other and try again.